# Я написал код , который делит списки на n списков , однако у меня возникает ошибка: IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, list

```
n = int(input())

k = int(input('На сколько частей разбить?'))

list = [0 for e in range(n)]

for j in range(len(list)):

    list[j] = int(input('Введите число:'))

    for i in reversed(range(1, k + 1)):
        super = []
        split_point = len(list)//i
        super.append(len(list[:split_point]))
        list = list[split_point:]
        if len(list[:split_point]) == 1:
            print(-1)

        elif len(list[:split_point]) > 1:
            print(super)
```

Comment: Что будет, если n не делится на k - разве в этом случае все чаcти будут длиной split_point?

Comment: А что делает вот эта строка `list[j] = int(input('Введите число:'))`, я не понял?

Comment: [lst[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n)]

Comment: Сергей Ш , это вместо какой строки вписать?